# How to obfuscate Spring Boot application with Zelix KlassMaster?

Tags: java, obfuscation

I'm having trouble obfuscating a Spring Boot application using Zelix KlassMaster.
I tested it with a standard maven application and it worked.
I tried with ProGuard, but it doesn't have a tool to obfuscate strings. And it seems that with Spring Boot Zelix behaves badly!

I need help! Does anyone have any example ZKM scripts?

Comment: Have you tried emailing their support team? I'm sure they've had customers with Spring Boot. They'll probably have some prior experience that would be helpful to lean on.

Comment: Actually, Spring boot is specifically addressed in their FAQ: https://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/FAQ.html#Q5 - seems like its just a matter of configuring it properly